# Samba can't access to directory created by local user

Tags: linux, windows, samba

I have samba share

```
[Attachments]
        acl_xattr:ignore system acls = Yes
        acl_xattr:default acl style = windows
        dos filemode = true
       acl allow execute always = Yes
       acl group control = Yes
       inherit acls = Yes
       inherit owner = windows and unix
       inherit permissions = Yes
       path = /opt/share/Attachments
        valid users = @local.lan\"Domain users"
        write list = @local.lan\"Domain users"
```

when local linux user "Bob" create directory
/opt/share/Attachments/bob_dir

samba users can't create files and folders in it, why?